# Dualboot Win10 & linux: where to install bootloader?

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo Y520 laptop, and want to install ElementaryOS (ubuntu based) alongside it.
Windows10(SSD) only boots in uefi, and linux(HDD) only in legacy mode.
(SSD is only visible in bios in UEFI mode, HDD is ony visible in bios in legacy mode)

Where do I need to install my bootloader, or /boot to achieven dualboot 
(without changing uefi/legacy in bios?)

Partition table: [drive0: HDD] [drive1: SSD]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQHG.png

Sata controller mode: SRT (windows came preinstalled)

---

I know this kind of questions are asked and answered many times, but I didn't find an answer (yet) that has the same scenario as me (uefi/legacy & ssd/hdd)

---

---